# Deploy REST API with Firebase implementation to Heroku using CircleCI

Tags: java, git, firebase, heroku, circleci

I've been looking into trying to deploy my REST API to Heroku using CircleCI. I don't think that the API calls that are secured by a Firebase Authenticator that check if the refresh token is valid, can be accessed because I don't push my Firebase Admin SDK to my public GitHub.

Is there a way that I can maybe make a specific file or folder in GitHub private so that my SDK isn't out in the open? This is the easiest way I can come up with.

How do you guys fix this? Because I could make my GitHub repo private whenever I want to deploy my API to Heroku. This takes up much time and I think there is a more efficient way.

Comment: I have no knowledge on firebase SDK but as I understand, you want to put in some heroku deployment keys in circleci and you don't want to put in Github. You can add environment variables in CircleCI. Also you can add ssh keys if you have.